# Transparent Circle in header bar CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit, fixed

Basically I want to see the Circle Cut-Out through the fixed header bar so I can see whats in the container when scrolling.

[image]

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: grey;
}
p {
    font-family: arial;
}
li {
    font-family: arial;
}
#page-header {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: orange;
}
#clip {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(10px);
}
```

Comment: Please add your markup to html/css questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `clip-path` you could use `box-shadow` by attaching a `:before` pseudo-element on `.header` to achieve this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: gray;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5000px orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

---

If you really want to use `clip-path`, I would suggest you to use `svg`'s `clipPath` for maximum browser support.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 700 50">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="c">
      <path d="M0,0 h700 v50 h-700 v-50 M345,25 a5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a5,5 0 1,0 -10,0" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,0 h700 v50 h-700z" fill="orange" clip-path="url(#c)" />
</svg>
```